# What to do with pages that don't need a Controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am going to keep this short.

In a MVC application pages with actions, user input etc need controllers but what are you supposed to do with a privacy policy page or an about page?

```
http://www.site.com/privacy-policy
http://www.site.com/about-us
```

They do not need controllers so is it best to somehow not have controllers for those types of pages and if so how would you do this while still keeping the same URLS?

Comment: I would just put the content in the view and let the controller return the view. Part of what you get with MVC is the template features.

Comment: Fragments "privacy-policy" and "about-us" seem more like actions for a controller, that deals with static content, but is made optional in routing =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to keep everything organized in the same manner. If these pages are static HTML then put them under a controller that serves static content, where each page will be a view. The controller would be trivial to write -- just a handful of lines.

To keep the URLs in the desired form you should use your framework's routing mechanism.

Comment: This is exactly what every mvc-framework I ever used does. Most of the time, there is a PagesController or a StaticController. Of course, you do not need any Model for this Controller.

Answer (score 1):

I have always created a route with all the possible "static" pages, an mapped that to a single controller, with multiple actions that return the view. Or a single action, which can take the URL as a parameter and it returns the correct view.

Bottom line, there are a lot of ways to do it. There may not be a "right" way to do it. You are correct that a new controller for each page is probably not the best way to do it.